# Get contact name of the sender from the sms table?

Tags: android

I am using the following to get the SMS from inbox

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,null,null, null);        
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

     cursor_count=cur.getCount();

    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {           
        do {

            sender.add(cur.getString(2));

            msg.add(cur.getString(11));
            date.add(formatter.format(Long.parseLong(cur.getString(4))));
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
```

I get the address of the person from the address field, but I also want to get the contact name of the sender, if stored in my contacts.
The person field always returns null, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code

```
 String contact=address;
                           Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
                           Cursor cs= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);

                           if(cs.getCount()>0)
                           {
                            cs.moveToFirst();
                            contact=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                           }
```

Comment: unable to import PhoneLookup ??

Comment: address is contact number.             
contact = cur.getString(2);
or 
contact = cur.getString("address");

Comment: please provide full working code or example, because I dont know where to place this code exactly while am getting all SMS log...

Comment: place this code in your broadcast receiver where you getting the new SMS, get the number(address) and continue with my code hope you get it